# 6MB shared L3 cache vs 8MB shared L3 cache

Tags: mac

How do I evaluate the difference btn two processors in MacBook Pro:
 2.7GHz quad-core Intel Core i7 processor (Turbo Boost up to 3.7GHz) with 6MB shared L3 cache

vs. 2.8GHz quad-core Intel Core i7 (Turbo Boost up to 3.8GHz) with 8MB shared L3 cache.

Comment: Well: 100Mhz and 2MB L3 Cache

Comment: Maybe have a look at the CPU benchmarks on the passmark website.  It so depends on workload but I'd probably go with the bigger cache over the 100MHz

Comment: Evaluate the difference in what way?  the 2nd processor is better in every way...

Answer (score 0):

Too bad what series it is is missing. Sandy vs Ivy Bridge... Although for the increased cache and speed the second is better.

Ideally, make sure they are of the same generation. A first generation i7 vs a current Ivy Bridge, go with the Ivy.

Otherwise, with the information you provided, the only deciding factor left is price. If the two cores are comparable in price and performance, get the second. But if you are looking at more than $100 difference, go with the first.